# Calling a function from a variable (PHP)

Tags: php, html, function, variables

I have a website I am making as a school project, and it appears I have jumped into something a bit too deep. I'm using PHP to create a page for each array object. In each page, I want to personalize the contents to match the page. For example, I have a page that gets created named `Darryl` and it's going to contain all my images. Other pages will be created and the contents of those pages will be created dynamically depending on the page.

What I am trying to do, is to change the `img src` using PHP and use a counter to make different images pop up. This is incredibly hard for me to explain.

I have this line of html code which contains the php(Which determines which images get shown:

```
 <td><img style="width:11em;" class="magnify" src="<?php print $imgSrc; ?>"/><br><?php print $pageName; ?></td>
```

The part i am having issue with is the " print $imgSrc; " part. This is the area where my php will create the src path. It uses this variable $imgSrc to get the correct path.

That variable is:

```
 $imgSrc = "images"."/".$pageName."/".counter();
```

Which writes the

Comment: I am having issues with the whole of my question being posted, please refrain from commenting on that whilst i try and fix the problem. It will not let me post as it is saying i have unformatted code but all my code is formatted.

Comment: What output out are you looking for in HTML?  image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg....?

Comment: I think that's not a good idea to have each page for each array object. That's why we're using PHP so we can have a single, one page "to rule them all".

Comment: I want the output for each html element to have a counter. Each will count up like this 1.jpg 2.jpg. 3.jpg. And it will put this into the src automatically allowing for additions.

Comment: Voitcus, im still a novice and cannot yet do that kinda of thing.. Trying to do a makeshift kinda thing really. the array has created the pages, but im just having issues with one line of coding. Which unfortunatly is not showing in my post because it cut off the post.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious I didnt understant the question clearly :), and i think, you are not using extension fo images try using this `$imgSrc = "images"."/".$pageName."/".counter() . ".jpg";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confused about what a function is or perhaps when it gets executed. If this is all the code you have on your page:

```
$imgSrc = "images"."/".$pageName."/".counter();
<td>
    <img style="width:11em;" class="magnify" src="<?php print $imgSrc; ?>"/><br>
    <?php print $pageName; ?>
</td>
```

Then `$imgSrc` is only ever written to once. So whatever `counter()` does, it only does once. You could wrap the whole thing in a for loop and do away withe the `counter()` call. You could remove the local variable of `$imageSrc` and make the attribute defined on the fly, like so:

```
<td>
    <img style="width:11em;" class="magnify" src="<?php print "images"."/".$pageName."/".counter(); ?>"/><br>
    <?php print $pageName; ?>
</td>
```

Then if the `counter()` function is stateful itself (as in, it returns a different value each time you call it), you're all set.

You can make a stateful function like the following:

```
$counter_var = 0;

function counter() {
    global $counter_var;
    return $counter_var++;
}
```

But globals are frowned upon, because the create hard to trace side effects (and other reasons). Most people would tell you to use a for loop. I only mention it because it looks closer to what you were trying to do in your original code.

Comment: I very much like this answer, it has helped my understand why my problem is happening. I believe i can try and fix it now.

Comment: Oh, important note I completely missed (props to Rafee): you definitely need a file extension on your image source. If your images don't have an extension on disk, odds are good that your web server won't serve them with the proper mime type header. PS glad I could help and sorry the editor was giving you a headache.